# Git commit file in the past, but not set it to the HEAD?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm got a bunch of old archived versions of files that were never in source control that I'm working on putting into a Git repo on GitHub. The most recent version of the files I committed already into the repository. So the most recent version in the master branch is the HEAD:

```
commit ab8d0899d5d17968fde96e483bf19a5222a6d981 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:17:53 2018 -0600

    Initial commit with newest files
```

But now, I would like to commit the old files using the original dates of when they were created. I have figured out how to do this:

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2001-11-03 00:00:00"
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2001-11-03 00:00:00"
git commit -am 'Adding old file from 2001'
```

So now the repo shows this commit being at the older date, which is perfect. However, this commit (even though it is dated to be much older than the other commit), is the HEAD commit on the master.

My log now looks something like this:

```
commit dbb7c6af9dac6dcf76614c2ac3506361b3ed5d95 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 3 00:00:00 2001 -0600

    Adding old file from 2001

commit ab8d0899d5d17968fde96e483bf19a5222a6d981 (origin/master)
Author: Me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:17:53 2018 -0600

    Initial commit with newest files
```

So when I view the repo on GitHub, the master branch shows the OLD commit from 2001 instead of the latest version. How do I fix this so that the latest commit is the HEAD?

I tried doing a hard reset using the commit `ab8d0899...` but that essentially just deleted the 2001 commit.

Is it possible to accomplish this without having to "recommit" the latest file just to make it the HEAD again?

Comment: Basically you want `Adding old file from 2001` commit to be below ` Initial commit with newest files`. Am i right ?

Comment: Yeah, so when you look at it in the log it actually looks like it was committed more recently even though the date is old. Because right now when you look at `git log` or even look at it in Sourcetree or on GitHub, it makes it look like it's the most recent commit even though it's dated 2001. The problem with this is that if you download the files from GitHub, now the default file is the 2001 version instead of the 2018 version.

Comment: Assuming you can do force push (personal repo), `git rebase -i head~2` and swap first two lines, then save the file. Definitely you will get conflicts as it is same file, resolve it and the order will be changed in local. Now you have to do force push. Btw `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` will not change the order of commits.

Comment: So does each commit have some sort of hidden, uneditable commit timestamp which is what actually determines the chronological order of commits?

Comment: All commits have *two* timestamps, but that's not the actual issue here. More important is the fact that each commit lists its *parent* commit(s), by hash ID. Git uses these to chain the commits together. A branch name like `master` contains one single commit ID, which is the ID of the *end* of the chain: the *tip* commit. Git then works backwards, from the tip to the root. Adding a new commit consists of writing a commit with the current tip as its parent, then storing the new commit's hash into the branch, updating the saved tip ID.

Comment: Hmm okay. Is it possible to reorder them?

Comment: Agree with @torek. It is possible to reorder. Please try rebasing which I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @JakeWilson Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Not yet. I get a lot of merge conflicts that don't seem to want to be resolved when rebasing. Still working on it though.

Comment: Rebase is not the way to do this. There is not a particularly *good* way to do this at all, but if you had a large, complex repository, careful graph splicing with `git replace`, followed (optionally) by a `git filter-branch` to rewrite everything using the replacements, would probably be the way to go. That's a nontrivial exercise with nontrivial consequences, though, so if you are just creating the repository now, creating it anew is going to be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can run `git rebase -i --root`. In the rebase editor you can swap the commits. However you'll likely run into lots of merge conflicts. Especially if you do this after you have committed all the different versions.

The cleanest way, IMHO, is actually delete and recreate the repo, then commit the files in the chronological order. I.e. commit the latest version last.